# Multiple instructions in Regex

Tags: regex

Suppose I have this text :

```
qsdfq fmld - 123 -mqlskdj -6464  - qlsdkjflj - 54654 -qsdfqsdf -2542
```

And I want to capture all numbers. A solution could be :

```
\D*(\d*)\D*(\d*)\D*(\d*)\D*(\d*)
```

But I don't know how many numbers I have. So I want to use the + sign.
I tried the following but it does not work :

```
[\D*(\d*)]+
```

Comment: Can't you just do `\d+` and get all matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `\d+` and global flag ( g )

```js
let str = `qsdfq fmld - 123 -mqlskdj -6464  - qlsdkjflj - 54654 -qsdfqsdf -2542`
let op = str.match(/\d+/g)

console.log(op)
```

**On side note:** I have JS code just to show a working example.